# How to ignore duplicate xsd elements while generating proxy class wsdl scheme in .NET

Tags: .net, wsdl, soapui, svcutil.exe, wsdl.exe

I need to generate .NET (C#) proxy classes from wsdl scheme

http://hh.ru/services/VacancyService?wsdl

but I receive an error:

```
The global element 'http://ns.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15:InternetDomainName' has already been declared.
```

I tried to use wsdl.exe, svcutil.exe tools from MS VS 2012 and 2010 without any success.

It's possible to avoid that error while generating proxy classes in SoapUI (by Axis 1.X wsdl2java tool) and unchecking noImports checkbox.

Is there any way to make wsdl.exe or svcutil.exe ignore duplicate xsd elements? Or maybe modifying downloaded wsdl scheme?

P.S.: The current web service presented "as-is" and it's no chance to change it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option. Your best option is to write your own utility that downloads the WSDL and removes the duplicate definitions before passing the file to xsd.exe.